# jQuery if and else with filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a filter and used this script for the filter.

```
filteredData = filteredData.filter(function() {
  var elm = $(this),
  price = parseInt('0' + elm.attr('data-price'), 10) || 0;
  if ($(price < 15)) {
    return !(250 <= price);
  } else {
    return !(sliderData <= price);
  }
});
```

But something is wrong. The price value is 15 or more. But the code never enters the else structure.

Comment: Your `if` is actually evaluating a jQuery object (`$(...)`) -- any non-null/not falsey value in an if check will cause the check to pass and the code in the `if` to evaluate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `$()` function call from this line:

```
if ($(price < 15)) {
```

It should be:

```
if (price < 15) {
```

The `$()` function returns an object, and all objects are "truthy" so this code would always go into the `if` block rather than the `else` block.

(By the way, assuming you fix the above problem, within the `if` branch the expression you are returning `!(250 <= price)` will always be `true` because `price` will be `< 15`, so you might as well just say `return true;` at that point.)

Comment: Thanks, can you give a example of the fix the above problem. Now i set it to if(price < 15){ But now he fire's both of the statements. The lower than en the else statement. But the price value is 15.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in that comment. If the price value is exactly 15 that will go to the `else` branch because 15 is not less than 15.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have put the '$' selector unintended:

Try just:
    if (price < 15) {
(...)

Answer (score 0):

I sense some isue with your `if` statement.

```
filteredData = filteredData.filter(function() { 
            var elm = $(this), 
            price = parseInt('0' + elm.attr('data-price'), 10) || 0; 
            if (price < 15) { 
                return !(250 <= price); 
            } else { 
                return !(sliderData <= price); 
            } 
        });
```

This would help.